# Windows Server Domain Controller doesn't forward DNS queries from client

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, nat, internet, dns-zone

I have a virtual network set up with VirtualBox. I have two Windows Server 2012 R2 hosts, named **DC01** and **EX01**. DC01 is a Domain Controller,DNS server and Router; EX01 is a DNS client and joined in the domain Jonas.Aalst.

Here is an overview of the servers:

**DC01**

- Function in network: AD Domain Controller, DNS server and Router
- Interfaces: **NAT** (resolved with DHCP) and **Internal Network** (Statically assigned with IP 192.168.17.1, mask 255.255.255.0)
- One DNS zone, a primary DNS forward lookup zone with records for **DC01* and **EX01**.

**EX01**

- Function in network: Exchange server (not installed yet) and DNS client
- Interfaces: **Internal Network** with IP 192.168.17.2, mask 255.255.255.0 , default gateway 192.168.17.1 and prefferred DNS server 192.168.17.1

At home, both DC01 and EX01 have internet access (DC01 via NAT , DHCP; EX01 via router DC01). But at my school network , only DC01 has internet access. EX01 can ping DC01 and can resolve local hostnames, but the server can't resolve internet websites (like www.google.com).

Does anyone know a possible solution?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS server **DC01** can act as DNS forwarder  either (unless you configure DNS Forwarding) resolve names through the root hints.

For DNS Forwarding configuration (root hints does not seem to work in your network - they are configured by default) try:

1. Open the DNS snap-in
2. In the console tree, right-click **DC01**, and then click
   **Properties**.
3. In the **Properties** sheet, on the **Forwarders** tab, click **Edit**.
4. Click the text entry area where indicated, type an IP address or DNS
   name for a DNS server that will receive forwarded DNS queries, and
   then click **OK**. *You can use the DNS server address issued by DHCP on Internet connected interface.*
5. When the IP address resolves to the server’s fully qualified domain
   name (FQDN) on the **Forwarders** tab, click **OK**.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Configuring DNS forwarders worked. Thank you very much. Marked your reply as "Solved".

Comment: I'm happy to help!